# Angular 6 background image crossfade animation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a problem with an animation in angular 6. I'm not sure if i'm doing everything right, but i have prepared stackblitz with a part of code of my component.

What I want to achieve is smooth animation when the item appears when *ngIf statment is fulfilled, but now it looks like the states of two children elements placed in crossfade-images component are treated like one element (i'm not sure if my assumptions are correct). But i wanted to do something looking like: on first load first item slides down from the top, after some interval this item should slide down, and in the same time another child of crossfade-images should slide from the top and it should happen in infinite loop

Could you guys check my stackblitz and give me a hand?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9srri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble that you are having is that `transform: 'translateY(-100%)'` positions the elements and then applies the transform after they are positions. Thus, the way that you have it set up is:

[image]

The boxes indicate where the images are positioned, with yellow being the first image and red being the second. What you will want to do is `position:absolute` your images (with the container being `position:relative` and transition from `bottom: "100%"` to `top:"100%"`

https://angular-gwxfta.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

I have left `transformY(-100%)` and just added `position: relative` to parent container, and `position: absolute` to children divs and it works as I wanted. Thank you so much.

Link to working code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9srri)

Comment: Welcome! It was fun to try to figure it out! :D